# PDF to HTML conversion / Regex replace and concat matches in Python

Tags: python, regex, pdf-to-html

I have written a pdf to Excel converter.
The conversion is done by linux command pdftohtml but sometimes it looks strange like these:

```
<b>1 </b><br>
In<br>
I t<br>
n r<br>
t o<br>
r d<br>
o u<br>
d c<br>
u t<br>
c i<br>
t o<br>
i n<br>
o  <br>
<i>Headline1: </i>Text1 <br>
text<br>
<b>1.1 </b><br>
Pu<br>
P r<br>
u p<br>
r o<br>
p s<br>
o e<br>
s  <br>
<i>Headline2: </i>Text2 <br>
text<br>
```

Obviously it should look like this:

```
<b>1 </b>Introduction<br>
<i>Headline1: </i>Text1 <br>
text<br>
<b>1.1 </b>Purpose<br>
<i>Headline2: </i>Text2 <br>
text<br>
```

I used multiple approaches, for example getting last characters and concat later by

```
<b>((?:[\d]+)(?:[.][\d]+)*)\s*</b><br>\s(\w{2})<br>\s(\w\s(\w)+<br>\s)*(\w)\s\s<br>\s<i>
```

but this doesnt return every letter. So whats wrong, why doesn't return this not all matches?
Further more I try to replace every `<br>`-Tag between `</b>` and `<i>`

```
(?=</b>.*)(<br>)(?=.*<i>)
```

but it doenst work as well.

Are these approaches right or is there a better one?

Comment: Are you converting to HTML or Excel?

Comment: I'm converting first in HTML by pdftohtml and use this for further manipulation

Comment: can you describe based on what you keep/remove ```<br/>``` ? describe it in English and someone might convert it to REGEX or code

Comment: I strongly recommend spending time to fix the converter instead of using a *complex* workaround.